# C# Thread reinitialization while running

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have globally declared a thread

`private Thread _ftpthread ;`

this thread is used to upload image to ftp

and in my function i have used

```
 private void uploadImage()
{

...
...
_ftpthread = new Thread(() => sendThumbsToFTP(path,image));
_ftpthread.Start();

_ftpthread = new Thread(() => sendThumbsToFTP(path2,image2));
_ftpthread.Start();
...
...
}
```

my question is Can i initialize thread like this? whether first thread will be terminated while re initializing it?
or both will be executed?

Comment: Any reason to start a thread and not use a `Task`?

Comment: @zmbq i dont have much knowledge on `Task` and `Thread`, whether to use thread or task.

Comment: It's rather strange coding to (mis-)use the variable _ftpthread like that. What do you use that "global" variable for? And if it's not used globally you could declare a local variable in your uploadImage() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

- *Can I initialize thread like this?*

  Sure, why not?
- *Whether first thread will be terminated while re initializing it? or both will be executed?*

  Both will be executed, and the first thread will simply run to completion.

---

The `_ftpthread` field is just a reference to the created thread and there shouldn't be any hidden semantics to overwriting the reference - aside from losing the ability to reference it. Your code is therefore almost*** equivalent to:

```
private Thread _ftpthread;

private void uploadImage()
{
    //...
    new Thread(() => sendThumbsToFTP(path,image)).Start();

    _ftpthread = new Thread(() => sendThumbsToFTP(path2,image2));
    _ftpthread.Start();

    //...
}
```

***I say almost because in a multi-threaded environment there is a chance another thread accesses `_ftpthread` between the two assignments in your original code and gets the reference to the first thread created. But if no other threads access `_ftpthread` the code snippets are equivalent.

Comment: +1. Re: _"The `_ftpthread` field is just a reference to the created thread and there shouldn't be any hidden semantics to overwriting the reference"_: Perhaps it's important to explain why there are no hidden semantics: A `Thread` object encapsulates an unmanaged resource; and because threads are unmanaged, they are never automatically reclaimed by the garbage collector. *That* is why a thread will not be stopped/destroyed just because it is no longer referenced by a variable.

Comment: @stakx Yes it is worth mentioning. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

both will execute together, and in hear 2 thread will run together,
and first thred will not terminated.

you can create method like this, if you want use TPL insted of using Thread directly

```
private void uploadImage() {
    Parallel.Invoke(
        () => sendThumbsToFTP(path,image),
        () => sendThumbsToFTP(path2,image2));
}
```

also you can see this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963549.aspx to know how can you use Tasks.